# How to get complete call heirarchy in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, profiling

I want the list of all functions called as a tree. I'm not talking about the stacktrace of one method call, but the something like the profiling tool in netbeans.

Something like this:

```
a()
  b()
    c()
  d()
    e()
      f()
  g()
```

And may be this can also include the time taken for each method call.

Answer (score -1):

The combinaison ctrl+alt+h provide the cal hirearchy. To find a feature in Intellij you can also type ctrl+shift+a and type what you need.